# Wordpress Plugin Development - Output to Body

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm writing a plugin that integrates Facebook login with my site (the only method of user authentication).  One of the last challenges I'm facing on this is integrating the login / logoff piece into the web site.  What I mean, is that I'd like to add a "Sign In / Register | Logoff" to the top right of every page / post (header of the site) for the HTML output to the site.  My goal is to not create a child theme and integrate plugin code into the theme code unless absolutely necessary... basically the plugin should be theme agnostic.

I have the code ready to go with respect to the login / logoff piece, I simply need to get it to output to the correct place.  My research so far has lead me to being able to put data into the `<head></head>` section, and also manipulate the body_class.  I've not found anything yet that facilitates output to the body section.

Anybody have any direction to provide?

Comment: You could make it a widget, but the appearance of the website is defined in the theme.

Comment: Certainly an option and not one I've considered.  Looking at the widgets screen, I only see areas for "right sidebar", "left sidebar", "footer widget area one", "footer widget area two", and three "footer widget area three".  Am I only limited to those areas?

Comment: In your theme you can provide the locations for the widget areas yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You can use wp_footer to the add code and align with CSS to make it position

```
<?php
function your_function() {
    echo '<p>This is inserted at the bottom</p>';
}
add_action('wp_footer', 'your_function');
?>
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_footer

Comment: Ah, very interesting approach.  With CSS and such, I have to get out of the mindset that footer code means the content ends up at the bottom of the page.  My only concern would be whether I can make this theme agnostic.

Comment: I hope that you mean no theme files should be edited. Yes, You don't need to make any changes to theme files.

Comment: Right... what I mean though is that themes are created with their own CSS.  If I can't figure out a way to use WP standard CSS, then I'll have to figure out what the theme creator did for adding the content where I want.

Comment: That's a uncontrollable thing from plugin. But still you can add it like as floating box or align it via CSS positioning.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a single function like

```
function show_authentication(){
   //your code to load the log in  goes here
}
```

you can show it in every page/post if you just call this function any where in you header.php file but i would suggest you to put it just after you call your menus in a

```
<span> <?php show_authentication(); ?> </span>
```

Comment: Yes but he said that he doesn't want to edit theme files, and `header.php` is a theme file. The OP wants his plugin to work with any theme.

Answer (score 0):

The only action hook available to display content in the body is the `wp_footer`, see @AchinthaSamindika's answer. Once your content is displayed in the footer, your question becomes mainly  a CSS issue.

Here is a basic example (forked from @AchinthaSamindika's answer):

```
<?php
function your_function() {
    echo '<div class="your_class">This is inserted at the bottom in the dom, but can be displayed in the top via CSS.</div>';
}
add_action('wp_footer', 'your_function');
?>
```

And then you would adjust the display using simple CSS:

```
.your_class {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 300px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

You can do literally anything, like pushing the entire body by adding margin-top to the body element, and then display your stuff above it either with `position: absolute;` or `position: fixed;` (to keep it sticked to the top even while scrolling), etc.

Because you cannot predict where a theme will display the navigation (horizontal/vertical menu, fixed, static, left, right, etc.) you cannot place an element with the certitude that it won't overlay on something else (e.g. the logo). What you could do is give the end-user the ability to adjust the positioning of your plugin's element via an option in the backend.